# Enable Applocker via Local Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, applocker

I'm trying to enable Applocker for a standalone un-managed SOE. I've enabled the Application Identity Service, Created default executable rules, and set Executable Rules to "Enforce Rules" with "Configured" ticked.

I've restarted several times, confirmed group policy settings via gpresults, and created specific deny publisher, file hash, and file path rules.

No matter what I do nothing will show up in Event Viewer "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Applocker/EXE and DLLs".

Is it even possible to enable Applocker just using gpedit.msc rather than Group Policy Management?

Edit: I should clarify that this SOE is NOT Domain joined.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is showing in the Event viewer then Applocker is not running. Applocker requires the Application Identity Service to be running. Did you check that?